# Uninstalling Postgres Rubygem on Windows 8.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

*copy and paste* "Hi, I'm new to Ruby/Ruby on Rails."

I'm running Windows 8.1. I have two outdated versions of the PostgresSQL Rubygem (`pg`) installed on my device: -v `0.9.0` and -v `0.18.2`. I'm trying to uninstall both, but when I enter the command `gem uninstall pg -v '0.9.0'` for example, it's as if nothing happened. I installed `-v 0.9.0` apart from bundle install.

I have already tried using the command:

```
ruby -e "`gem list`.split(/$/).each { |line| puts `gem uninstall -Iax #{line.split(' ')[0]}` unless line.empty? }"
```

This was supposed to remove everything - but it removed everything except the `pg` gems. What command should I be using to uninstall the `pg` gems?

Comment: use this command `net user postgres /delete` to uninstall Postgres

Comment: Hi James, welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is good, although the formatting got messed up a bit on the long "ruby -e" line. Be careful with the `net user` command that @rick mentions, that deletes the postgres *user* (nothing to do with Ruby or gems).

Answer (score 0):

Try `gem list --details` to see where your "pg" gems are installed. Perhaps they're in a different directory from where you expect (perhaps with unusual permissions).

Try `bundle clean --force` to remove all the gems that aren't part of the bundle. (You can also add `--dry-run` to see what it plans to do.)

And depending on how you installed it, you might consider re-installing Ruby.

Good luck!